# livecode and mergext dropbox sync

Tags: livecode

i am using mergext dropboxsync to synchronise my data from the ipad.
my question is.
how we get the file from the special folder specialfolderpath
and how we check if the file exist into the dropbox.
i am no using fields for folder or the files i want the procedure to be hidden from the user
to get my folder and path i use the simple bellow code.

```
put specialfolderpath("documents") & "/myfile.sqlite" into myPath
```

and here is the code from the button i use

```
on mouseUp
  goToParent --<command
  repeat for each line tempitem in fld "sFolders" --<hide field
   add 1 to t
if tempitem ="hairaid-backup" then
  put 1 into fExist
end if
end repeat
 --!! if folder exist
if fExist is a number then
else 
  try
  mergDropboxCreateFolder (hairaid &"-"&backup) 
catch e
 answer e
 end try
end if
end mouseUp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not really recommend synchronising a sqlite database over dropbox. You are likely to have better results creating a tree for files for dropbox to sync as one large file is likely to end up with conflicted versions.

However, answering your question in the general sense you would need to do something like this:

```
put url ("binfile:"&myPath) into myData
mergDropboxWriteFile relativePath,myData
```

Then to get the data you:

```
put merDropboxGetFile(relativePath) into myData
```

Comment: for the app i use,is only one file the .sqlite that need to be sync so the end user don't loose the data,there is Nothing else from the documents folder that end user need to have.from the other side i see that the MergdropBox have revisions,is possible to have both sync and simple in the app?the answer for the question is working thx.